# Get First Child Page ID or Permalink in WordPress Admin

Tags: functions, wp-admin

I have a navigation set where the content doesn't exist on the parent page, but rather on a page called Overview which is the first child of the parent.

eg: About is the first level page, but when you click on About in the main navigation it redirects you to the first child page. In my case this first child page is called Overview. This redirect is being done by custom page template which is assigned to the About page.

In an effort to make things less confusing for the editor team once the site is live and so they don't accidentally try to add content to the About page, I've disabled the page editor via a function. I now want to display an alert in the WordPress admin whenever someone edits the About page so they get a notification which says "No Content is edited here. Please edit the Overview page."

I ultimately want to have the alert allow they to click on "Please edit the Overview Page" and have them taken to the respected page.

I've already written the code to remove the editor box and display the message. The part I am stuck on is how to lookup the permalink or the post ID of the first child page in the admin. I've done it before on the frontend to display info about the first child, but it seems it relies on frontend only accessible functions.

Here is the full code for everything I have thus far.

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'hide_editor' );
function hide_editor() {
        $post_id = $_GET['post'] ? $_GET['post'] : $_POST['post_ID'] ;
        if( !isset( $post_id ) ) return;

        $template_file = get_post_meta($post_id, '_wp_page_template', true);

    if($template_file == 'page-redirect.php'){ // edit the template name
        remove_post_type_support('page', 'editor');
    }
}

add_action( 'edit_form_after_title', 'redirect_page_template_notice' );
function redirect_page_template_notice(){
    echo '<div class="error inline">
       <p>No content is added here. Please edit the Overview page.</p>
    </div>';
}

add_action( 'admin_notices', 'edit_first_child_page' );
function edit_first_child_page() {

    global $my_admin_page;
    $screen = get_current_screen();

    if ( is_admin() && ($screen->id == 'page') ) {
        global $post;
        $id = $post->ID;


        echo 'Current page id is ' . $id;
    }
}
```